# Adjusting Marker Size in Scatter Plot when using 'size' argument

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

Lets say i am creating a scatter plot on polar projection in matplotlib. I assign the markersize to a variable using the size argument. On the resulting plot, the markers are very small and some of the barely visible. I also need a legend to display the actual values of the different sized markers. So i need to increase the markersize but without changing the labels in the legend (so s=3*t doesnt work as it changes the labels in the legend). What would be the best way to do this?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.style.use('default')
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(r, s, c=c, s=t, cmap='copper')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
plt.legend(*c.legend_elements('sizes', num=3), loc=(1, 0.8))
plt.show()
```

In this example, r, s, c, and t are simple 1d arrays

[image: The plot]

Comment: Isn't it essential that the size of the markers on the scatter plot and the markers in the legend match, and isn't it inconvenient for visualization if they are different? I have added `ax.legend(*c.legend_elements('sizes', num=3), loc=(1, 0.8))` to the [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-scatter-py) to confirm.

Comment: Yes, the markers in the plot and the legend need to have the same size, and this could be changed by using s=3*t (in my example). What is neccessary is keeping the labels in the legend the way they are right now (25, 50, 75) while changing the size of the markers. Using s=3*t changes the raw values and thus the labels in the legend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [official sample](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-scatter-py), I customize the legend label. I get the legend and the label, and rewrite the value of the label.
There may be a way to get the values from the latex format, but I have not been able to find out.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# Compute areas and colors
N = 150
r = 2 * np.random.rand(N)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
area = 200 * r**2
colors = theta

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)
# ax.legend(*c.legend_elements('sizes', num=3), loc=(1, 0.8))
handlers, labels = c.legend_elements('sizes', num=3)
labels[0] = r'$\mathdefault{50}$'
labels[1] = r'$\mathdefault{75}$'

ax.legend(handlers, labels, loc=(1, 0.8))
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Graph before modification**

[image]